# How do i get css working inside php echo?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have following line to delete the post, but can't get the css working there. Anyone help please?

```
<?php if (current_user_can('edit_post', $post->ID)) echo "<a type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" href='" . wp_nonce_url( get_bloginfo('url') . Blockquote "/wp-admin/post.php?action=delete&amp;post=" . $post->ID, 'delete-post_' . $post->ID) . "'onclick=\"return confirm('Are you sure?');\"> title="Delete"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i>&#8203"?> </a>
```

Comment: Sorry i mean the bootstrap css class

Comment: Use single quotes on HTML code instead of double quotes.

Answer (score 1):

this is a portion of your code  `echo "<a type=";button;" class=";btn; btn-primary; btn-xs;"`

... why the ; ? the concat symbol is the dot (.)

After the question edit:

```
<?php 
if (current_user_can('edit_post', $post->ID)) 
 echo 
  "<a type='button' class='btn btn-primary btn-xs' href='" . wp_nonce_url( get_bloginfo('url') . Blockquote "/wp-admin/post.php?action=delete&amp;post=" . $post->ID, 'delete-post_' . $post->ID) . "' onclick='return confirm('Are you sure?');'> title='Delete'><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove'></i>&#8203</a>"
 ?>
```

try this change.

Answer (score 0):

Use echo statement started by single quote , and end with single.
use escape sequence in place of javascript quotes
like /'
all u will able to run this code in just quick editing.